# Installing Tmux 2.5 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, tmux

I downloaded the tar.gz file from the official tmux page, and did a ./configure, then make and make install, and I get

```
    ubuntu@pc:~/Download/tmux-2.5$ sudo make install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Download/tmux-2.5'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c tmux '/usr/local/bin'
make  install-exec-hook
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/Download/tmux-2.5'
if test xmdoc = xmdoc; then \
    sed -e "s|@SYSCONFDIR@|/etc|g" ./tmux.1 \
        >./tmux.1.mdoc; \
else \
    sed -e "s|@SYSCONFDIR@|/etc|g" ./tmux.1| \
        gawk -f./mdoc2man.awk >./tmux.1.man; \
fi
/bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./tmux.1.mdoc \
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/tmux.1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Download/tmux-2.5'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/Download/tmux-2.5'
```

I have no clue what this means. How can I upgrade from Tmux 2.1 to 2.5, without crashing my already open sessions?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error, could you post what you get with `tmux -V` ?  I did exactly the same as you and it is indeed correctly installed.

In fact, the following line in your `sudo make install` output

```
/usr/bin/install -c tmux '/usr/local/bin'
```

means that `tmux` executable is copied under `/usr/local/bin`.